# Multiple Bluetooth Smart sensors for bike?

Tags: speed, bike-computer, cadence, software, heart-rate

I just bought a Sports Tracker Smart heart rate monitor that communicates via Bluetooth. Then I saw the cadence sensor that also measures speed and distance plus it communicates with Bluetooth Smart. I did some research and found out that there's a communication standard called ANT+. Neither of these devices support it.

Is it possible to use these simultaneously with my phone that has Bluetooth Smart? Currently the Sports Tracker cadence sensor is not supported with Android (or not with their software at least. Maybe with something like Runtastic Road Bike) but they plan to release a software update in summer that makes it work on Android.

Also, what softwares on Android you know that can support this combo?

Answer (score 3):

Android can just about handle multiple BTLE sensors simultaneously but there are still some low level Android bugs that make it rather unreliable.  The coding for is also a good bit more complex to get working than the single sensor case.  I have support in my app IpBike via a [beta version of IpSensorMan](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=btle-beta)

At this point in time if you were getting new then an ANT+ based setup is the preferred route.  But if your looking to work with your current phone which is not ANT capable then you would need an ANT USB stick and things get messy.

Comment: I read on the Sports Tracker website that one could use the heart rate monitor and the cadence sensor simultaneously over Bluetooth Smart, I think that's going to work then and if not, I have a reason to return it. My phone (Nexus 5) apparently has a chip inside that works with ANT+, but this is not enabled on software level. I'd need to root the phone and enable it via a 3rd party software.

Comment: The Nexus 4 & 5 have notoriously bad BLE software. It's very difficult to keep BLE devices connected reliably. Some Samsung phones (S4?) support ANT+.

Comment: S4 does support ANT+, but I haven't experimented with how well it works.

Comment: ANT+ is far more reliable than BLE.  Having code supporting both I know where my user queries are.

Answer (score 2):

I found driod support for these kinds of sensors to be patchy at best and not yet what I consider ready for prime time. Manufacturer provided software is often crap, third party often don't support the hardware. Many claims of features and devices suppported apply to the iPhone versions only.

I current use Digifit iCardio on my driod phone with Scorche sensors.

What I found:

Bluetooth and ANT+ are completely different and incompatable technlogy. 
The Andriod Version on your phone, manufacturer and model can be important. 
Many manuals etc are for the iPhone version, when the driod version is quite different.

Overall its a currently a crap shoot if things work as they are supposed to. You could waste a lot of time, or it might "just work" if you are really lucky.

Comment: Agreed. I think if the OP really wants to measure these data then they might need to think about a proprietary route at the moment. But this route involves cost.